# Admob InterstitialAd + RewardView not shown after loading

Tags: android, admob

I'm adding Admob ads into my app, I've previous experience with banner ads, but i'm trying now with InterstitialAd and Rewarding videos, What I've added and i'm sure about :

1. Permissions .
2. Google Play Service latest sdk / Firebase-ads .
3. Firebase json .
4. Google play service meta .
5. Adview activity in AndroidManiFest.xml

My code is as the following :

```
        InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("MYACCOUNT/MYADUNIT");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("283D63FED5A2DD63F96FDE3EBF4F5D1F").build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
        mInterstitialAd.show();
```

the account / id unit are correct, and the log says :

```
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
type=1400 audit(0.0:34603): avc: denied { read } for name="mem" dev="debugfs" ino=6327836 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs:s0 tclass=file op_res=-13 ppid=674 pcomm="main" tgid=674 tgcomm="main"
I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
E/Ads: JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)
I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
E/Ads: JS: Uncaught Error: apmc:nocon (https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20160726/r20110914/abg.js:32)
```

Now, Reward videos, the code is as the following :

```
                    mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(SettingsFragment.this);
                    mAd.loadAd("ACCOUNT/ADUNIT", new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("283D63FED5A2DD63F96FDE3EBF4F5D1F").build());
                    if (mAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mAd.show();
                    }
```

Log :

```
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

What's the problem here ? everything is correct and following the SDK, the ads were created 7 hours ago .

Answer (score 0):

So i got the answer from the Official Admob SDK team, in Google forums.

For Interstitial problem, i need to set the "isLoaded" and "showAd" in "OnLoaded" listener in InterstitialAd .

And for Video problem, there's no test ads for Video Reward, also i need valid meditation account linked with Video Reward .